# how to read a string after each comma using Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

How to show in Category when I get it from API like  `Category: "Art,History,Culture"`,

In .html I used this code

```
                       <mat-card-actions>
                            <button mat-stroked-button color="primary"
                                style="float: left;">{{ subEntry.Category}}</button>
                        </mat-card-actions>
```

but show a button `Art,History,Culture`
I want to show 3 button: button `Art` , button `History` , button `Culture`

Can you share with me any idea please?

Comment: You need to first split your category string into an array, and then loop over the array using the `*ngFor` directive in your template. How to split a spring has been answered numerous times, and the standard Angular documentation should show you how to apply `*ngFor` to your template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In component.ts file once you get response from API and store it in an array and use *ngFor directive on html to iterate through that array and add buttons accordingly.

//component.ts

```
categories : string[] = []
apiCall().subscribe(response =>{
   this.categories = response.split(',')
});
```

// component.html

```
<div *ngFor='let category of categories'>
 <button mat-stroked-button color="primary"
                                style="float: left;">{{ category }}</button>
</div>
```